# Node.js - Express.js JWT, how to check token expired or not?

Tags: node.js, express

how to check whether my token is expired or not?

```
var token = jwt.sign(user,app.get('superSecret'),{
    expiresIn : 2
});
```

Answer (score 27):

I assume you are using the jsonwebtoken package that is [documented here](https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken#tokenexpirederror)

If that is the case, have a look at the `jwt.verify` method:

```
jwt.verify(token, 'shhhhh', function(err, decoded) {
  if (err) {
    /*
      err = {
        name: 'TokenExpiredError',
        message: 'jwt expired',
        expiredAt: 1408621000
      }
    */
  }
});
```

In short words: Check the error of that method. If it is the TokenExpiredError then, guess what... the token is expired.

Comment: Actually i set 2 seconds for token expiration, but my token is not expired.

Comment: there is no error!.. even it crossed more than 5 minutes, can u pls explain this...

Answer (score 18):

```
var isExpiredToken = false;

var dateNow = new Date();

if(decodedToken.exp < dateNow.getTime()/1000)

{
       isExpiredToken = true;
}
```

Comment: Hello, lakshman. I see what you're doing in dividing the date by 1000 (because `exp` is in seconds), which the top answer has wrong. While this seems to be a valid answer to the question, you might be better off suggesting this as an edit on the top voted answer instead (as long as you have a clear edit summary that explains _why_ the current code is wrong). As it is, this answer has somehow entered the [low-quality posts queue](/review/low-quality-posts/20385182) and might get deleted. Cheers!

Comment: The reason it is in the LQ queue is probably because it is a code-only answer. Adding some explanation why this solution is better than the other similar solution would help.

Answer (score 7):

```
var isExpiredToken = false;

var dateNow = new Date();

if(decodedToken.exp < dateNow.getTime())

{
       isExpiredToken = true;
}
```

Comment: that's wrong. `dateNow.getTime()` returns millis while `decodedToken.exp` is in seconds

Answer (score 0):

```
var isExpiredToken = false;
var seconds = 1000;
var d = new Date();
var t= d.getTime();


if (decoded.exp < Math.round(t / seconds)) {
  // code...
  isExpiredToken = true;
}
```

Source:
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_gettime.asp

Answer (score 0):

You need set the host current time to compare the expiration date in the verify function example:

`jwt.verify(token, JWT.SECRET_KEY, {clockTimestamp: new Date().getTime()}, callback)`

the clockTimestamp property is required to set the host current time.

Answer (score 0):

The best way set the code in your parent component of page or wrapper.
Your need delete your old (expared) token.

```
 let token = localStorage.getItem( 'token' );

 jwt.verify( token, 'yourkey', function(err, decoded) {

    if ( err ) {

    localStorage.removeItem( 'token' );

    }

  } );
```

Answer (score 0):

in place "expires in" use key name as "iat"...hope it will work

Comment: why should "iat" (issued at) be used? iat is the time when the token was issued, not when it expires.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add an error instance

```
const decoded = verify(token, process.env.TOKEN_KEY || '', (err: any, decoded: any) => {
  if (err instanceof TokenExpiredError) {
    return res.status(401).send({ success: false, message: 'Unauthorized! Access Token was expired!' });
  }
  if (err instanceof NotBeforeError) {
    return res.status(401).send({ success: false, message: 'jwt not active' });
  }
  if (err instanceof JsonWebTokenError) {
    return res.status(401).send({ success: false, message: 'jwt malformed' });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is method works for me.

If you set an expiry date on the signed token. JWT will validate it for you.

**Sign a token.**

```js
  try {
    const token = jwt.sign({ uuid: '123456' }, JWT_SECRET, { expiresIn: '1min' })
    return token
  } catch (error: unknown) {
    if (error instanceof jwt.JsonWebTokenError) {
      return error.message
    }
  }
```

**Verify**

```js
try {
    const token = ''
    const decoded = jwt.verify(token, JWT_SECRET)
    return decoded
  } catch (error: unknown) {
    if (error instanceof jwt.JsonWebTokenError) {
      return error.message
    }
  }
```

After 1 minute(`expiresIn: '1min'`), then the token will become invalid.